# AssertionError: Could not determine version from string 'Redshift 1.0.32574 on Amazon Linux, compiled by gcc-7.3.0'

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-redshift

I am using the python pandas library to read data in reshift warehouse. The command pd.read_sql() fails with the error message, **AssertionError: Could not determine version from string 'Redshift 1.0.32574 on Amazon Linux, compiled by gcc-7.3.0'**

Anyone here knows how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue from a recent cluster (patch) upgrade where the version string format changed. Apps that expect a specific string format so they can parse to ensure it's a supported version can error out. See https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=998260&#998260 for an AWS contact you can ping for immediate fix. If you have a support agreement with AWS, you can create a ticket there also.

Comment: thanks, I was able to resolve this; it seems for versions of Python above 3.7, the best solution is to edit the base,py file in the directory _/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql_ . In our case, adding redshift to the function 
**_get_server_version_info** resolved this 

Our code changed from from 
` m = re.match(
            r".*(?:PostgreSQL|EnterpriseDB) "`
to this 
       ` m = re.match(
            r".*(?:PostgreSQL|EnterpriseDB|Redshift) "`

`

Comment: cool, so you modified your client version check to accept the new string. That works too though probably not for all users.

Comment: yes, I agree it might not work for all users